# populate select input with array

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to start out saying I don't want to use Javascript....

I have an array which is returning correctly I believe, however I am only having the first entry in the array display in the drop down list.

Is this a problem with the array? or with this function?

```
foreach($array as $key=>$value){
    $html = "<option value='$key'>$value</key>";
}

echo "<select name="process">$html</select>";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the concatenation operator (`.`):

```
$html = '';
foreach($array as $key => $value)
{
    $html.= "<option value='$key'>$value</option>";
}

echo "<select name=\"process\">$html</select>";
```

However, looking at the function you posted earlier, `mysql_fetch_assoc` only returns a single row at a time. You need to loop over that, instead. The following should suffice:

```
function tasks_list($p_id) { 
    $project_tasks = array(); 
    $p_id = (int)
    $p_id; 
    $func_num_args = func_num_args(); 
    $func_get_args = func_get_args(); 

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT task_name FROM tasks WHERE project_id = $p_id");
    while($project_tasks = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        $html.= "<option value='".$project_tasks['task_name']."'>".$project_tasks['task_name']."</option>";
    }

    echo "<select name=\"process\">$html</select>";
}
```

Comment: Hi ben this is perfect and working great! Although it displays the select box twice? I assume I am referencing the function correctly? tasks_list($p_id)

Comment: Yes, that's the correct way to call the function, but you must be calling it twice.

Answer (score 1):

```
$html = "";
foreach ($array as $key => $value){
    $html .= "<option value='$key'>$value</option>";
}
echo "<select name='process'>$html</select>";
```

`=` reassigns; `.=` appends

If you use `=` it reassigns `$html` in every iteration, so that `$html` will contain the result of the last iteration - one single option.

Comment: Okay, I am still only recieving one value, does this mean that there is a problem with the array?

Comment: Are you sure that you haven't done any error while copying my code?

Comment: yes 100%, would you be able to take a look at my array please?

Comment: I don't see your array? Show it.

Comment: function tasks_list($p_id) {
 $project_tasks = array();
 $p_id = (int)$p_id;
 
 $func_num_args = func_num_args();
 $func_get_args = func_get_args();
 
 $project_tasks = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT `task_name` FROM `tasks` WHERE `project_id` = $p_id"));
  
 return $project_tasks;
}

Comment: @user2286553 That will only return a single result.

Comment: ^ is the function I use to generate the array. I have tested the mysql query and it works in my db. Below is where I am referencing it in the document

Comment: $project_tasks = tasks_list($p_id);  I have checked and $p_id returns the correct value

Comment: @user2286553: LIke I told you in your last question: `mysql_fetch_assoc` returns one row!  You need to call it in a while loop.  See the docs: http://php.net/mysql_fetch_assoc

Comment: Yes the array only contains the first result. `$result = mysql_query("SELECT task_name FROM tasks WHERE project_id = $p_id"); while ($task = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) $project_tasks[] = $task;`

Answer (score 1):

You need to concat the strings. Start by initializing `$html` to an empty string before starting your for loop.

```
$html = '';
foreach($array as $key => $value)
{
    $html .= "<option value='$key'>$value</key>";
    // same as $html = $html . "<option value='$key'>$value</key>";
}
```

**Note:** There is also a typo in your code:

```
echo "<select name="process">$html</select>";
```

should either be:

```
echo "<select name=\"process\">$html</select>";
```

OR

```
echo "<select name='process'>$html</select>";
```

if that's what you meant.